# How to set the text of optional labels in .kv from .py

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have problem with setting the labels texts.
I need to set different text on the different labels that just have an id in .kv file, so that means that I don't want to create a class for each of the labels.
But I want to have the access to changing each labels text.

Please, help me with that problem on Python 3.6 and Kivy 1.11.1

There is my main.py code:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivymd.label import MDLabel
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.metrics import dp, sp, pt

def toast(text):
    from kivymd.toast.kivytoast import toast

    toast(text)

class MyScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.menu_items = [
                {
                    "viewclass": "MDMenuItem",
                    "text": "text%d" % i,
                    "callback": self.callback,
                }
                for i in range(1, 3)
            ]

        self.menu_button = None

    def change_variable(self, value):
        print("\nvalue=", value)
        self.VARIABLE = value
        print("\tself.VARIABLE=", self.VARIABLE)

    def callback(self, *args):
        toast(args[0])

class MainApp(App):
    title = "KivyMD MDDropdownMenu Demo"
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        return MyScreen()

    def results(self):

        msc = MyScreen()

        msc.ids.firstlabel.text = 'FIRST TEXT'
        msc.ids.secondlabel.text = 'SECOND TEXT'
        msc.ids.thirdlabel.text = 'THIRD TEXT'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

There is my main.kv code:

```py
#:import MDDropdownMenu kivymd.menus.MDDropdownMenu
#:import MDRaisedButton kivymd.button.MDRaisedButton
#:import MDLabel kivymd.label.MDLabel

<OptionalLabel@MDLabel>:
    halign: 'center'
    font_size: dp(12)

<MDRB@MDRaisedButton>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 3 * dp(48), dp(48)
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    opposite_colors: True

<MDMenuItem>:
    on_release:
        app.root.change_variable(self.text)
        app.root.menu_button.text = self.text

<MyScreen>:
    name: 'myscrn'
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_y: 'center'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.5
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
            spacing: dp(10)
            MDRB:
                id: mainbutton
                text: 'MDButton1'
                on_release:
                    root.menu_button = mainbutton
                    MDDropdownMenu(items=root.menu_items, width_mult=4).open(self)
            MDRB:
                id: secondbutton
                text: 'MDButton2'
                on_release:
                    root.menu_button = secondbutton
                    MDDropdownMenu(items=root.menu_items, width_mult=4).open(self)
            MDRB:
                text: 'set the labels'
                on_release:
                    app.results()
            OptionalLabel:
                id: firstlabel
                text: 'label1'
            OptionalLabel:
                id: secondlabel
                text: 'label2'
            OptionalLabel:
                id: thirdlabel
                text: 'label3'
```

Thanks for attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close. Accessing a text by ids is the way you want to go, you just have another issue here.

In short, you are actually creating two different MyScreen objects, you have one in your build() (which is actually what shows on the window) and then you are creating another screen in local scope of the "results" function.

```
class MainApp(App):
title = "KivyMD MDDropdownMenu Demo"
theme_cls = ThemeManager()

def build(self):
    return MyScreen() ///THIS IS A OBJECT IN MEMORY

def results(self):
    msc = MyScreen() /// THIS IS A DIFFERENT OBJECT IN MEMORY, BUT DOESN'T REFERENCE THE SCREEN IN Build

    msc.ids.firstlabel.text = 'FIRST TEXT'
    msc.ids.secondlabel.text = 'SECOND TEXT'
    msc.ids.thirdlabel.text = 'THIRD TEXT'
```

In this situation, I'd suggest taking your results function and bringing down into your MyScreen class like the below example. Key point here, you can bind to the on_release function from either KV lang or in Python Class. In the example below, I'm doing so in Python class.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivymd.label import MDLabel
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.metrics import dp, sp, pt


Builder.load_string("""
#:import MDDropdownMenu kivymd.menus.MDDropdownMenu
#:import MDRaisedButton kivymd.button.MDRaisedButton
#:import MDLabel kivymd.label.MDLabel

<OptionalLabel@MDLabel>:
    halign: 'center'
    font_size: dp(12)

<MDRB@MDRaisedButton>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 3 * dp(48), dp(48)
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    opposite_colors: True

<MDMenuItem>:
    on_release:
        app.root.change_variable(self.text)
        app.root.menu_button.text = self.text

<MyScreen>:
    name: 'myscrn'
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_y: 'center'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.5
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
            spacing: dp(10)
            MDRB:
                id: mainbutton
                text: 'MDButton1'
                on_release:
                    root.menu_button = mainbutton
                    MDDropdownMenu(items=root.menu_items, width_mult=4).open(self)
            MDRB:
                id: secondbutton
                text: 'MDButton2'
                on_release:
                    root.menu_button = secondbutton
                    MDDropdownMenu(items=root.menu_items, width_mult=4).open(self)
            MDRB:
                id: changesresultsbutton
                text: 'set the labels'
            OptionalLabel:
                id: firstlabel
                text: 'label1'
            OptionalLabel:
                id: secondlabel
                text: 'label2'
            OptionalLabel:
                id: thirdlabel
                text: 'label3'
""")
def toast(text):
    from kivymd.toast.kivytoast import toast

    toast(text)

class MyScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.menu_items = [
                {
                    "viewclass": "MDMenuItem",
                    "text": "text%d" % i,
                    "callback": self.callback,
                }
                for i in range(1, 3)
            ]

        self.menu_button = None
        self.ids.changesresultsbutton.bind(on_release = self.results)

    def change_variable(self, value):
        print("\nvalue=", value)
        self.VARIABLE = value
        print("\tself.VARIABLE=", self.VARIABLE)

    def callback(self, *args):
        toast(args[0])


    def results(self, value):
        self.ids.firstlabel.text = 'FIRST TEXT'
        self.ids.secondlabel.text = 'SECOND TEXT'
        self.ids.thirdlabel.text = 'THIRD TEXT'

class MainApp(App):
    title = "KivyMD MDDropdownMenu Demo"
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        return MyScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```